# Repeating decimals in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, integer

Okay, so I am building a program that will be dealing with percents of cash values, and am studying php to build it in. If I understand it correctly, PHP's integers can only handle numbers of up to 11 numbers according to the manual. So, what would happen if a repeating decimal/really long decimal were put into the php through division?

Furthermore, (this may not be the right place to ask, but then again) does anyone know how paypal would react to being charged values that have numbers smaller than cents (like $12.134)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would just truncate after so many.  Not entirely sure.  And  I have no idea about the paypal thing.  That looks like something to ask their support.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be truncated, once you've passed a value into a variable pretty much that variable will keep the accuracy of that value.